# How I can rotate a polar chart?

Tags: highcharts

I want a polar chart (with highcharts library), but I need the chart is rotated 45º. I have the following base script:

```
$(function () {

var interval = 90;
var startAngle = 0;

window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        polar: true,
        margin: 60
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Style of thought',
    },
    pane: {
        startAngle: startAngle
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        startOnTick: true,
        tickInterval: interval,
        min: 0,
        max: 360
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: interval
        },
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Luis',
            data: [40, 60, 35, 89]
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Media de comunidad',
            data: [60, 75, 15, 52]
        }]
    });
});
```

[Example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CL27V/1/) and the chart nice.

I need to rotate the chart 45º, for this I change the value of  startAngle to 45

```
$(function () {

var interval = 90;
var startAngle = 45;

window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        polar: true,
        margin: 60
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Style of thought',
    },
    pane: {
        startAngle: startAngle
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        startOnTick: true,
        tickInterval: interval,
        min: 0,
        max: 360
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: interval
        },
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Luis',
            data: [40, 60, 35, 89]
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Media de comunidad',
            data: [60, 75, 15, 52]
        }]
});
});
```

[Example 2 in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CL27V/) and now the chart is bad. If you see it, the center of the circle is not equidistant from the circumference.

Any idea of the problem?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug, so I've reported to our devs here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1561

Thanks for suggestion